# No module named theme.urls

Tags: django, heroku

I just deployed my first django app to the Heroku platform. I basically followed [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django), just that instead of creating a dummy `django-admin.py startproject hellodjango .` django app, I used my app that currently works on my Windows PC. When deploying the app and running the server on heroku I get a `No module named theme.urls`.

Here is the traceback. Any ideas?

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://severe-winter-1546.herokuapp.com/

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'themes',
 'haystack')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  298.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  328.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  323.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named theme.urls
```

And my settings.py

```
# Django settings for theme project.
import os
import dj_database_url
ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1


USE_I18N = True


USE_L10N = True


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'files')


MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/'


STATIC_ROOT = ''


STATIC_URL = '/static/'


ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'theme.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
'C:/Users/leonsas/Desktop/dj/theme/templates',
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'registration',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'themes',
    'haystack',

)
#required for haystack. Using Whoosh
HAYSTACK_WHOOSH_PATH = 'C:/Users/leonsas/Desktop/dj/theme/files/Whoosh/index'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE = 'whoosh'
HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'theme.search_sites'



LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that the error was that heroku created the app in a folder named 'app' instead of 'theme'. I tried renaming the app via the heroku CLI using

```
heroku apps:rename theme
```

but for some reason I cant figure out still, it gave a `You do not have access to appname` error. So instead I just went and changed every part of my code that had theme.foo to app.foo. And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The urls.py of the main project has the wrong setting, this is what i can deduce from the exception trace. Please use something like this mentioned below in the main project urls.py.

```
(r'^home/', include('MAINPROJECT_NAME.APPNAME.urls'))
```

Comment: I really don't know why would I do this, but I still did it and the error is still there.

Comment: Please mention your settings file and the themes.urls.py file on pastebin. So that a solution can be inferred.

Comment: Just posted setting.py on my question. I currently have no themes.urls.py (and it runs fine on my Windows computer). Also, note that 'theme' is the project and 'themes' is the app within the project.

Comment: I don't wanna sound needy :-). But please post your theme.urls.py on pastebin in this case.

Comment: Here we go: http://pastebin.com/9QriDPQ5 Keep in mind that this works in my Windows environment, but its when I moved it to Heroku that it fails

Comment: As you don't have a themes.urls.py, therefore you don't need  (r'^home/',include('theme.themes.urls')) in the theme.urls.py. As i can see url(r'^theme/', include('theme.foo.urls')) was the line initially. Whats foo ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12671/discussion-between-sazpaz-and-dan-boa)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you've misnamed something. Check out the ROOT_URLCONF and INSTALLED_APPS:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'theme.urls'
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'registration',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'themes',
    'haystack',
)
```

Your INSTALLED_APPS says `themes` with an `s`, but your ROOT_URLCONF says `theme` without the `s`. Try getting those in sync..